# Is it any git able text editor for MAC?

Tags: git, macos, editor, plugins

Is it any extension for git for MAC users? I would like to use git integrated with TextWrangler or any text editor in my MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend for everybody to use **[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) as git GUI front end** on Mac. **Git + SourceTree + Dropbox** what we use in our company to sync our daily work. SourceTree is free yet.

If there is something you can not handle in SourceTree, than it is good to know that the default text editor is vim. The most important shortcuts for vim are the following:

- **Press 'i'** to get into 'edit / insert' mode from 'view' mode
- **Press ESC** to get back to 'view' mode
- Write in view mode **':wq'** to quit vim and save changes

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what you're asking. I use TextWrangler as my text editor from git. In TextWrangler, under the application menu, choose "Install Command Line Tools". That installs /usr/bin/edit. Then in my ".gitconfig" file I use:

```
editor = /usr/bin/edit -w
```

This makes TextWrangler my git text editor. So when I run a git command like "git commit -a", TextWrangler will open and I can enter my commit comment. When I close TextWrangler I am taken back to the Terminal where I can continue using git.

Comment: Just want to add that I tried to install the tools from the TextWrangler version you can download via the AppStore and no "Install Command Line Tools" menu point was available. Only a fresh download direct from the [Bare Bones Software Site](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) offered me this option.

Comment: in MacOS, i did `editor = edit` after installing command line tools

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the Git Bundle for TextMate is what you need http://blog.macromates.com/2008/git-bundle/

Answer (score 0):

Coda 2, you can Git Add, Commit, Push, Pull and more within the editor.